# Dynamic components loading at certain location in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-template

I am developing a new application in Angular2 and I have a requirement where I need to load some 8 controls(grid,charts, calendars e.t.c) dynamically on my application. I am able to load all those controls dynamically. But my requirement is to display them in particular fashion like two controls per row which I am unable to do. At present all the controls are loaded but all in one column one below the other.

The below code shows how I got the gadgets list and how I am adding it to the component using viewContainerRef. But I couldn't able to control where this components can be displayed.

```
   for (let gadget of gadgets) {
                        this.userService.getGadgetsData(gadget.Id).subscribe(gadgetsData => {

                            switch (gadget.Name) {
                                case "PieChart":

                                    this.donughtChartData = gadgetsData.Data.Issues.map((v: any) => ({
                                        category: v.Values[0].Value,
                                        value: v.Values[2].Value,
                                    }));

                                    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DonutComponent);
                                    const ref = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(factory);
                                    ref.instance.donutchartData = this.donughtChartData;
                                    ref.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();

                                    break;
```

Comment: Show us what you have done so far so we can help you

Comment: I have updated the question with some code. Here I am able to get all the components dynamically and display them. But couldn't able to control how they can be displayed. like two controls per row.

Comment: What about your template ?

Comment: You mean the template of the controls?

Comment: The template of your component

Comment: The template of the loader component is empty. That is very I am blocked.  As it is empty, the loader components displays all the dynamic components one after the other. I am not sure how to control the display of the dynamic components.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said I think this: 
you need to display the content *put* into your template/ .html file. your typescript will run fine but no where to view. use a div or something in your template and display that result.

once it is displayed you can give that div a class name of whatever ex " class='flex-box' and apply the styles below. They will automatically align them into columns and is very easy to understand; just give the link a read.

You want to use flex to achieve the columns

example here:

```
`ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
     li{
      flex: 6 1 ; //the number refer to how much/fast the item will grow/shrink
       .form-control-item {//...some css}
      }
    }`
```

IF your question now turns into 'How do i use the template' then you need to look at other stack overflow Q's as that has been answered many times. you can also refer to the angular docs, and take the  [Hero's Tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/)

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I have updated the question with some of my code. So here I am able to get the controls/components and load them in a different component. But I couldn't able to control the display location of these components in the loader component.

Comment: load them into this components template and use flex box to achieve columns.

Comment: Here based on your suggestion, I could load the components one after the other. But in my case, I create a dynamic component and I know the row/column location that I have to insert this component So basically, I have bunch of dynamic components with known row/column location. I need to display them on my page.